# Search the rest columns of pyspark dataframe for values in column1

Tags: python, search, pyspark

Suppose there is a pyspark dataframe of the form:

```
id  col1  col2 col3 col4
------------------------
as1  4    10    4    6
as2  6    3     6    1
as3  6    0     2    1
as4  8    8     6    1
as5  9    6     6    9
```

Is there a way to search the ***col 2-4*** of the pyspark dataframe for values in ***col1*** and to return the ***(id row name, column name)***?
For instance:

```
In col1, 4 is found in (as1, col3)
In col1, 6 is found in (as2,col3),(as1,col4),(as4, col3) (as5,col3)
In col1, 8 is found in (as4,col2)
In col1, 9 is found in (as5,col4)
```

*Hint:* Assume that col1 will be a set {4,6,8,9} i.e. unique

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can leverage the Spark SQL `.isin` operator.

Let's first create the DataFrame in your example

Part 1- Creating the DataFrame

```
cSchema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType()),\
StructField("col1", IntegerType()),\
StructField("col2", IntegerType()),\
StructField("col3", IntegerType()),\
StructField("col4", IntegerType())])


test_data = [[1,4,10,4,6],[2,6,3,6,1],[3,6,0,2,1],[4,8,8,6,1],[5,9,6,6,9]]


df = spark.createDataFrame(test_data,schema=cSchema)

df.show()

+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|   4|  10|   4|   6|
|  2|   6|   3|   6|   1|
|  3|   6|   0|   2|   1|
|  4|   8|   8|   6|   1|
|  5|   9|   6|   6|   9|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

Part 2 -Function To Search for Matching Values

**isin**: A boolean expression that is evaluated to true if the value of this expression is contained by the evaluated values of the arguments.
http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

```
def search(col1,col3):
    col1_list = df.select(col1).rdd\
    .map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()
    search_results = df[df[col3].isin(col1_list)]
    return search_results

search_results.show()

+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|   4|  10|   4|   6|
|  2|   6|   3|   6|   1|
|  4|   8|   8|   6|   1|
|  5|   9|   6|   6|   9|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

This should guide you in the right direction. You can select for just the Id Column etc.. or whatever you are attempting to return. The function can easily be changed to take more columns to search through. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Nadim. As you rightly stated it would be good if the function can be changed to take more columns to search through

Comment: I have actually used the isin() method before. The drawback is it can be used for a one-to-one column match.

Answer (score 1):

```
# create structfield using array list
cSchema = StructType([StructField("id", StringType()),
                      StructField("col1", IntegerType()),
                      StructField("col2", IntegerType()),
                      StructField("col3", IntegerType()),
                      StructField("col4", IntegerType())])

test_data = [['as1', 4, 10, 4, 6],
             ['as2', 6, 3, 6, 1],
             ['as3', 6, 0, 2, 1],
             ['as4', 8, 8, 6, 1],
             ['as5', 9, 6, 6, 9]]

# create pyspark dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(test_data, schema=cSchema)

df.show()

# obtain the distinct items for col 1
distinct_list = [i.col1 for i in df.select("col1").distinct().collect()]
# rest columns
col_list = ['id', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

# implement the search of values in rest columns found in col 1
def search(distinct_list ):
    for i in distinct_list :
        print(str(i) + ' found in: ')

        # for col in df.columns:
        for col in col_list:
            df_search = df.select(*col_list) \
                .filter(df[str(col)] == str(i))

            if (len(df_search.head(1)) > 0):
                df_search.show()


search(distinct_list)
```

Find full example code at [GITHUB](https://github.com/taiwotman/pyspark-dataframe-searcher)

```html
Output:

+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|as1|   4|  10|   4|   6|
|as2|   6|   3|   6|   1|
|as3|   6|   0|   2|   1|
|as4|   8|   8|   6|   1|
|as5|   9|   6|   6|   9|
+---+----+----+----+----+

6 found in: 
+---+----+----+----+
| id|col2|col3|col4|
+---+----+----+----+
|as5|   6|   6|   9|
+---+----+----+----+

+---+----+----+----+
| id|col2|col3|col4|
+---+----+----+----+
|as2|   3|   6|   1|
|as4|   8|   6|   1|
|as5|   6|   6|   9|
+---+----+----+----+

+---+----+----+----+
| id|col2|col3|col4|
+---+----+----+----+
|as1|  10|   4|   6|
+---+----+----+----+

9 found in: 
+---+----+----+----+
| id|col2|col3|col4|
+---+----+----+----+
|as5|   6|   6|   9|
+---+----+----+----+

4 found in: 
+---+----+----+----+
| id|col2|col3|col4|
+---+----+----+----+
|as1|  10|   4|   6|
+---+----+----+----+

8 found in: 
+---+----+----+----+
| id|col2|col3|col4|
+---+----+----+----+
|as4|   8|   6|   1|
+---+----+----+----+
```